# LSTM multiple feature regression data preparation

Tags: time-series, lstm

I am modeling an LSTM model that contains multiple features and one target value. It is a regression problem.
I have doubts that my data preparation for the LSTM is erroneous; mainly because the model learns nothing but the average of the target value.

The following code I wrote is for preparing the data for the LSTM:

```
# df is a pandas data frame that contains the feature columns (f1 to f5) and the target value named 'target'
# all columns of the df are time series data (including the 'target')
# seq_length is the sequence length 
def prepare_data_multiple_feature(df):
    X = []
    y = []

    for x in range(len(df)):
        start_id = x
        end_id = x + seq_length
        one_data_point = []
        if end_id + 1 <= len(df):
            # prepare X
            for col in ['f1', 'f2', 'f3', 'f4', 'f5']:
                one_data_point.append(np.array(df[col].values[start_id:end_id]))
            X.append(np.array(one_data_point))
            # prepare y
            y.append(np.array(df['target'].values[end_id ])) 

    assert len(y) == len(X)
    return X, y
```

Then, I reshape the data as follows:

```
X, y = prepare_data_multiple_feature(df)
X = X.reshape((len(X), seq_length, 5)) #5 is the number of features, i.e., f1 to f5
```

is my data preparation method and data reshaping correct?

Comment: If there is no correlation between features and target you can get mean as the best guess. Can you provide the rest of your code, including the tensorflow model? Something that could be executed without guessing. It'd be even better to include the data for download. In the code snippet you posted future_test is not defined or explained. Basically provide a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

As @isp-zax mentioned, please provide a [reprex](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we could reproduce the outcome and see where the problem lies.

As an aside, you could use `for col in df.columns` instead of listing all the column names and (minor optimisation) the first loop should be executed `for x in range(len(df) - seq_length)`, otherwise at the end you execute the loop `seq_length - 1` many times without actually processing any data. Also, `df.values[a, b]` will not include the element at index `b` so if you want to include the "window" with last row inside your `X` the `end_id` can be equal to the `len(df)`, i.e. you could execute your inner condition (prepare and append) for `if end_id <= len(df):`

Apart from that I think it would be simpler to read if you sliced the dataframe across columns and rows at the same time, without using `one_data_point`, i.e. 
to select `seq_length` rows without the (last) target column, simply do:

```
df.values[start_id, end_id, :-1]
```